# Not able to take F5 session

Tags: powershell, f5

I am using below code to take F5 session and get the list of health monitors

```
$MyLTM_IP = "192.168.1.2"
$mycreds = Get-Credential
$session = $null
#Create an F5 session
$session = New-F5Session -LTMName $MyLTM_IP -LTMCredentials $mycreds 
$GetMonitorList = @()
$GetMonitorList = Get-HealthMonitor -F5Session $session
```

I have installed the `F5-LTM` module from below reference:

https://gist.github.com/joel74/f5acb78ca7dbe0d87bc95cab98de1388

the code is not giving any error but it is not taking any session(the $session variable to blank)

Please let me know what is the issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `-PassThru` switch parameter](https://github.com/joel74/POSH-LTM-Rest/blob/master/F5-LTM/Public/New-F5Session.ps1#L19) to make `New-F5Session` output the resulting session object:

```
$session = New-F5Session -LTMName $MyLTM_IP -LTMCredentials $mycreds -PassThru
```